# Take CGRect out of UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, cgrect

This must sound **really** weird but I want to take the keyboard's CGRect and take it out of the UITextView. Here is a picture to help:

[image]

I basically want the UITextView to become smaller so when I add text it scrolls down. If you need more info ask me.

**EDIT:** When I use this code:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)notification {
      NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
      kbSIZE = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
      CGRect newTextViewFrame = self.notesTextView.frame;
      newTextViewFrame.size.height -= kbSIZE.size.height;
      self.notesTextView.frame = newTextViewFrame;
 }
```

this happens:

[image: imag2]

Comment: Not only Not Weird, but preferred behavior.  It annoys me when apps don't do this and you have to dismiss the keyboard to see the last bit of the view. (normally a table view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that weird at all.  The same thing often happens with tableviews when you are bringing up a keyboard.  This bit of code should help.

```
CGRect newTextViewFrame = textView.frame;
newTextFrame.size.height -= keyboardSize.frame.size.height;
textView.frame = newScrollFrame;
```

Comment: Sorry sorry, I said scrollView and meant textView.  I have since edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Add back the height of the view you have sitting over the keyboard and that should fix the problem.

Comment: Call textView.inputAccessoryView.frame.size.height and add that value back in.

Answer (score 1):

This is not weird at all :)

You can do this by registering as an observer to the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` (it would be a good idea to also register for the `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` in the same process).

When the registered selector will be called, the notification parameter will contain the keyboard's size inside the `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` value of the `userInfo` dictionnary :

> [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size

All you need to do now is to set the frame of your UITextView to your desired size.

Be warned : the CGRect you get **does not take into account the device orientation**. This means, if the device is in fact in landscape mode, you'll need to switch the width and height of the CGRect for it to make sense in your context.

Comment: Does your UITextField go all the way to the bottom of the view before the keyboard is shown? What if you use `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` instead of `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` ? Also, you can press Command+S to take a nice screenshot of the simulator automatically.

Comment: Yes it goes to the bottom and it is a UITextView.

Comment: Well then you would need to find out why the values do not add up. Additionally, I see you added a custom inputAccessoryView over the keyboard. As it only show a "Done" button, I would suggest removing it. The "Return" button should do this job on the keyboard, or if you want to dismiss the keyboard on a tap outside, a simple UIGestureRecognizer would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Adam G. helped me with the problem.